# How can I correctly install Ruby on Rails, bundler, etc on a fresh Mac OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, installation

I recently reinstalled my Mac OS X (10.6.8) and want to install things properly this time.  I had some trouble last time so I just want to set things up right.

In particular, I want to install Ruby on Rails, bundler, and so on... but when I do "gem install bundler" I get the following error:

```
c-69-181-106-62:~ dave$ gem install bundler
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
    /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/dave/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
    gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
    bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
```

I'm confused... can someone help me out, or point me to an article saying "OK, first, add this to this file, then download this, then do this..."?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first warning is because you aren't `root`. The second warning is because you don't have something in your `PATH` (but I don't think that will be a problem if you're `root`.) The third error is because you have an out-of-date RubyGems. Try this:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: when I do `sudo gem update --system` I am getting `gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories.
If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.`

Comment: @arivarasan: Then you should update `gem` through `apt-get` instead. To update all installed packages, you can use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to first install [RVM](https://rvm.io/), then install bundler and Rails.

Comment: The reason this is so nice is because RVM creates its own user and puts all the gems inside its own folder. You don't have to worry about permissions of the usr/bin folder and using sudo.

Comment: I tried to install a specific version of ruby on my MacOS and when I do ruby -v it shows the version my mac came with instead.

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do it, it's also to sandbox the gems to your local user.

- For that just create a gems directory with:

`mkdir ~/gems`

(you can use any directory you have access at)

- Then configure the gems environment adding these lines to your shell start script (.bash_profile, .bashrc or .zshrc for instance):

`export GEM_HOME=~/gems
export GEM_PATH=~/gems
export PATH=$GEM_PATH/bin:$PATH`

- Restart your shell terminal
- Check your environment with the command

`echo $PATH`

(it should contain the new gems path bin directory)

- Update your rubygems with:

`gem update --system`

(calling with sudo can be required)

- Update the current gems:

`gem update`

- Install bundler (optional):

`gem install bundle`

And presto !!

NOTE: Also ensure you have Xcode Command Tools installed (if not much of the gems will not be able to build natively)